# How do I pass a reference to a component into another component via a mapped list?

Tags: reactjs

So I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
export const serviceList = [
  {
    title: "Exterior Services",
    image: "/images/service-card-images/kendall-painting.webp",
    description: "ExteriorServicesDescription",
    id: 1,
    link: "/services/painting",
  },
```

I am mapping this list to a card component where the info is displayed.  I decided I wanted some more complex jsx to display in the description than just a text blurb, (basically some p tags and a list), so I made a small component to display, for example `<ExteriorServicesDescription />`.  How can I pass this component, or a reference to this component, into the one rendering the information?

I have tried typing description as a React.ReactNode and just passing the component as `<ExteriorServicesDescription />` but linting only saw it as a type, and I also tried passing the name of the component as a string and then like this in the component:

```
{serviceList.map((service) => (
          <ServiceCard
            key={service.id}
            title={service.title}
            image={service.image}
            description={<service.description />}
            link={service.link}
          />
        ))}
```

but nothing renders to the page shows as `<exteriorservicesdescription></exteriorservicesdescription>`.

Here is the `<ServiceCard />` component:

```
import React from "react";
import ExteriorServicesDescription from "./ExteriorServicesDescription";
import Image from "next/image";


interface ServiceCardProps {
  title: string;
  image: string;
  description: React.ReactNode;
  link: string;
}

const ServiceCard = ({ title, image, description, link }: ServiceCardProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-4/5 flex flex-col items-center m-auto justify-center no-underline border-2 rounded-2xl shadow-black shadow border-black">
      <div className="w-full h-64 relative">
        <Image
          src={image}
          alt={title}
          fill={true}
          className="rounded-t-xl"
        />
      </div>
      <h2 className="text-xl no-underline bg-black text-gold w-full text-center py-2">
        {title}
      </h2>
      {description}
      <a
        href={link}
        className="text-lg border rounded-2xl border-black px-2 py-1 mb-2 hover:bg-slate-300 hover:scale-105 transition-all duration-100"
      >
        Learn More
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServiceCard;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please add your ServiceCard components code with your question.

Comment: JSON is a text format for transporting simple data. It can't represent things like React components, as those are at their base, functions, which JSON is incapable of representing. There are other ways of transporting the information, though, which others may provide. I suggest removing the references to JSON though, as I see nothing in the question that requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a specific component is responsibility of the React app, not of the API.

Just send a string and use an `if`/`switch` statement inside your component:

```
enum DescriptionTypes {
  Exterior,
  Interior,
};

interface ServiceCardProps {
  title: string;
  image: string;
  description: DescriptionTypes;
  link: string;
}

const ServiceCard = ({ title, image, description, link }: ServiceCardProps) => {
  function renderDescription() {
    if (description === DescriptionTypes.Exterior) {
      return <ExteriorServicesDescription/>
    }
    if (description === DescriptionTypes.Interior) {
      return <InteriorServicesDescription/>
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="...">
      ...
      {renderDescription()}
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`"ExteriorServicesDescription"` is a string in your case, it cannot behave like a react component.

If you have a react component named `ExteriorServicesDescription`, you should pass it directly as a value of `description` in `serviceList`.

```
export const serviceList = [
  {
    title: "Exterior Services",
    image: "/images/service-card-images/kendall-painting.webp",
    description: ExteriorServicesDescription, // The real component
    id: 1,
    link: "/services/painting",
  },
```